# Ubuntu 16.04 MPEG-2 license key, does it work?

Tags: kodi, ubuntu, mpeg-2

I am using Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2 and have hardware acceleration enabled by having MPEG-2 license key configured.

Now considering moving to Ubuntu 16.04.
Does anyone know if the license key can be installed the same way **and** confirmed hardware acceleration to be working on Kodi?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The MPEG-2 key is licensed to the Raspberry Pi you bought.  It allows the Raspberry Pi hardware to decode MPEG-2.

Comment: @joan, and we put the key into config.txt. I was wondering if it is the same procedure for non-Raspbian O/S and whether it would take effect

Comment: Are you saying you want to run Ubuntu on the Pi hardware?  I don't know what low level differences there may be between Raspbian and Ubuntu as far as the parsing of `/boot/config.txt` is concerned.

Comment: @joan Yes, I am interested in running Ubuntu 16.04 on Pi 2 so that I could get dotnet core apps to run on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPEG-2 key is bound to the hardware , not to any kind of operating system. It will work with any software
which is tailored to the Pis HW acceleration APIs (mainly OpenMAX IL).